# How Do I use auto layout to pin a label to the right side of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

Pinning a label to the left side of a uitableviewcell doesn't seem to work. when the view size changes it stays right where it is and gets cut off.

here is my constraint:

[image: picture of my constraint]

And here is what it looks like on a 3.5 inch phone, it is not staying pinned to the left side of the cell

[image: label is getting cut off]

Comment: The red box indicate you still have error on your constraints. Most likely it's because the label doesn't have y constraint. Can you try fix that and see if the cut off problem occurs at runtime (on simulator / device). I often get similar things on the storyboard / xib but it shows fine on simulator / device

Comment: I'd wager that the label's superview's right edge is under-constrained.

Comment: well clicking "Add Missing constraints" seemed to do the trick, thanks!

Comment: @FierceMonkey "Add missing constraints" is not guaranteed to add exactly the constraints that you need (one size does not fit all). Try to learn as much as possible about auto-layout, so that you can manually add the missing constraints yourself, to suit your particular layout needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

- just pin first label from (left,top,bottom)
- the right label (right,top, bottom)
- horizontal spacing between left and right label.

or

Only right label:

- make width and height constant and pin it right and vertical centre.

Answer (score 1):

The red box is show that you miss any constraint which is related to its position. If you set the vertically centre constraint. Hope this error remove and your UI give better response.